# C# solution won't compile due to different framework versions

Tags: c#

I have a C# solution that contains 3 projects.  Project1 was originally built in VS 2012.  Projects 2 and 3 which are class libraries were added to the solution later using VS 2015.  I have references in Project 1 to Projects 2 and 3.  When I try to build the solution, I get the following error:

"The referenced project 'ProjectA.TeamA' is targeting a higher framework version (4.5.2) than this project’s current target framework version (4.5). This may lead to build failures if types from assemblies outside this project’s target framework are used by any project in the dependency chain.  IntroductionToCSharp"

Is there a way to get Project 1 to use framework 4.5.2?  Thanks.

Comment: Vs menu go to project the name of your project properties placed at the bottom of project menu,like projectA properties click go to application the change target framework to 4.5.2.

Answer (score 6):

If you right-click the project in the Solution Explorer, you can choose `Project Properties`.

And on the left hand side pane, you can select `Application` and you'll see the following screen:

[image]

Now you can choose the `Target Framework` that particular project would use.

Keep in mind that depending on the libraries you've used etc., you'll have to be careful when upgrading/downgrading the framework.